# Similar Novels Algorithm

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for suggestions to improve the similar novels algorithm below. I would love if I can get some suggestions to reduce the time complexity.

Right now there are way too many nested loops which is causing it to have too many queries.

```
function update_similar_novels($post_id) {
        $taxonomies = get_taxonomies(array('_builtin' => false,), 'names');
        array_push($taxonomies, 'post_tag', 'category');

        $novel_terms = array();
        foreach ($taxonomies as $tax) {
            $novel_terms[$tax] = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, $tax, array('fields' => 'ids'));
        }

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'novel',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'fields' => 'ids',
        );
        $novels = get_posts($args);
        $simlar_novels = array();
        $m=0;

        foreach ($novels as $novel_id) {
            $simlarity=0;

            foreach ($taxonomies as $tax) {
                if (get_option('tax-weightage-'.$tax) =='0') {
                    continue;
                }
                
                $target_terms = wp_get_post_terms($novel_id, $tax, array('fields' => 'ids'));

                foreach($target_terms as $target_term_id) {
                    if (in_array($target_term_id, $novel_terms[$tax])) {
                        $simlarity += (int)get_term_meta($target_term_id, 'weightage', true);
                    }
                }
            }
            array_push($simlar_novels, array( 'id' => $novel_id, 'similarity' => $simlarity));
        }

        usort($simlar_novels, [$this, 'compare_weightage']);
        $top6 = array_slice($simlar_novels, 0, 6);
        error_log(print_r($top6, true));
    }
```